# Matlab Symbolic Diff Fails

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm working with the following code and I've run into a strange issue. If I do the following:

```
syms x n chebyprime(n,x)
chebyprime(n,x)=diff(chebyshevT(n,x),x);
```

The function outputs the expected result. But if I tweak it like this:

```
chebyprimeplus(n,x)=diff(chebyshevT(n+1,x),x)
```

It breaks the whole thing. Instead of a numeric output (Which would be expected of a derivative of a polynomial evaluated at a specific point) I get output like this:

```
>> chebyprimeplus(3,.2)

ans =

D([2], chebyshevT)(4, 1/5)
```

This is baffling behavior to me. It looks like it's outputting in some sort of mupad syntax, and I can't find any way to convert this to a numeric value. I don't see any reason simply upping the order of the chebyshev should cause the integration to fail and when I input a higher order by increasing the value of n it works fine so it's not an issue with the diff operator's ability to differentiate the chebyshev polynomial. Can anyone help me sort this out?

Thanks.